# ColdFusion - Create Time from Number of Minutes

Tags: time, coldfusion, formatting

I have the number of minutes (ie. 25, 120, 300, etc) entered by the user, and I need to display it in a h:mm:ss format. Are there any built-in ColdFusion functions that can do this for me, or does anyone have any suggestions about the easiest way to build out the string?

Comment: ``CreateTime(hour, minute, second)`` and then ``TimeFormat(time)``.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that, but in the documentation it states the the minute parameter has to be between 0 and 59, which doesn't work for the examples I gave above. Users can enter up to 999 minutes.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
<cfset totaltime = "#totalminutes\60#:#numberformat(totalminutes % 60, "00")#:00" />
```

Comment: Perfect! Should have thought of the math way myself.

Comment: Probably want to put a `int()` around `#totalminutes\60#`.

Comment: The backslash is "integer division" so results in the expected result. I've overlooked this before when editing others code.

Comment: @DanRoberts - I didn't notice the backslash (vs. the standard division operator). I was not aware there was even an "integer division". Very cool!

Comment: Good tip @Dan. I missed that operator. (Too bad I cannot up vote twice.)

Answer (score 13):

Kinda late to the game, but this works pretty nicely:

```
TimeFormat(CreateTimeSpan(0,0,minutes,0))
```

Comment: Neat idea. Just throw in a `"HH:mm:ss"` mask so it displays correctly for the upper ranges ie 999 minutes.