# Convert minutes to Hours and mins in coldfusion

Tags: date, coldfusion, coldfusion-11, coldfusion-2016

I want to convert 207 minutes to Houres and mins such as format (3 Hours 37 Mins). The User will enter 207 minutes and the output should be 3 hours and 37 mins.

Comment: It is a good idea to search first, as this is a common task. Possible duplicate of [ColdFusion - Create Time from Number of Minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10146820/coldfusion-create-time-from-number-of-minutes)

Answer (score 2):

Yikes at these answers.

Quick, elegant, smells like lavender:

```
<!--- This number is arbitrary, set it to whatever you want. --->
<cfset Minutes = 125>

<cfset HoursOutput = Minutes \ 60>
<cfset MinutesOutput = Minutes Mod 60>

<cfoutput>#HoursOutput# Hours and #MinutesOutput# Minutes</cfoutput>
```

[Using a backslash](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/2031-the-integer-division-operator-in-coldfusion.htm) instead of dividing normally eliminates the remainder in `HoursOutput` (which would be formatted by default as a long decimal number) for readability.

Comment: How is this better than the possible duplicates?

Comment: @JamesAMohler I only see one duplicate, and my answer is constructed differently enough that I felt it may have contributed something to the asker's understanding. There is something to be said for a simple line by line breakdown. Set this, output that. Whenever I find something on SO that I can copy and paste for a functional example of how an idea works, I feel a lot better about working with it. To each his own.

Answer (score -2):

Here is the solution

```
<cfset TotalMinutes = 307>
<cfset yourrequired_format= "#TotalMinutes \60# Hr #numberformat(TotalMinutes % 60, "00")# Min" />
```

Comment: The output will be (3 Hr 37 Min )

Comment: Your output is wrong. It's return **5 Hr 07 Min **. Can you manually calculate by yourself 307 / 60 = 5.111 then how will your get 3 hr as per you code ? So you are wrong.

Comment: Input was wrong too.